# Hide or show one view with constraint on it

Tags: ios, constraints

I have a ViewP with two subviews, viewA and viewB.
viewA is always there, but viewB should can't see in some condition.
And all these views are loaded from a xib.

My question is that, how can I update the viewP's heigh base on the viewA's heigh + ViewB's heigh. And if ViewB is hide, how to update viewP's heigh by several simple code, not update the frame by hard code.

First, I just setup the viewB's hidden. but the viewP can't update himself.

I have searched, and got a way that adjust the priority of two heigh constraint of a view. one with 0 heigh, another with 46 heigh, but when I change their priority by code. looks like it's not work for me.

Comment: Are you familiar with AutoLayout?

Comment: @Azat, not so much, just start to use it

Comment: I can make this change(like hide or show) in XIB file, but I just want to make those change by code, because there's several different condition.

Comment: You need just set constraints properly and connect `IBOutlet` to one of them (height of your view, as I guess) to be able to change its value from the code

Comment: @Azat I have already do this, I connect two constraint IBOutlet property, because in condition of hidden, I just want 0-heigh constraint would effect;  in condition of show, I just want 46-heigh constraint would effect.  So I change their priority both in code, switch between value of 250, 750. Not work for me.

Comment: No need to change `priority`, only `constant`

Comment: @Azat you mean change it's height value, not it's priority?  let me give a try.

Comment: @Azat it works for change constant, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a newcomer of Autolayout, I recommend this framework. With the major work as text art, it's easy and straightforward. You can find it in github.

Back to your question.
You can use QuickVFL API to do it:

```
/**
 *  Control the visibility of the view.
 *
 *  @param visible   whether show the view
 *  @param vertically whether vertically, or horizontally
 */
-(void)q_setVisibility:(BOOL)visible isVertically:(BOOL)vertically;
```

for Example:

```
[anyViewInstance q_setVisibility:NO isVertically:YES];
```

Jobs inside:

1. Add a constraint to limit target widget's width or height(depending on isVertical).
2. Set the constant value of the constraint to 0
3. Set the priority of the constraint to 1000(most hight)
4. > If any other constraint makes width or height larger than 0, its priority must be lower than 1000